# Icache and Dcache in Simple.py configuration of gem5

Tags: gem5

I am trying to understand the models generated using gem5. I simulated a build/X86/gem5.opt with the gem5/configs/learning_gem5/part1/simple.py configuration file provided in gem5 repo.
In the output directory I get the following .dot graph:

[image]

I have the following doubts:

1. Does this design not have any Instruction and Data Cache? I checked the config.ini file there were no configuration statistics such as ICache/Dcache size.
2. What is the purpose of adding the icache_port and dcache_port?

   `system.cpu.icache_port = system.membus.slave
   system.cpu.dcache_port = system.membus.slave`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does this design not have any Instruction and Data Cache? I checked the config.ini file there were no configuration statistics such as ICache/Dcache size.

I'm not very familiar with that config, but unless caches were added explicitly somewhere, then there aren't caches.

Just compare it to an se.py run e.g.:

```
build/ARM/gem5.opt configs/example/se.py --cmd hello.out \
  --caches  --l2cache --l1d_size=64kB --l1i_size=64kB --l2_size=256kB`
```

which definitely has caches, e.g. that `config.ini` at gem5 211869ea950f3cc3116655f06b1d46d3fa39fb3a contains:

```
[system.cpu.dcache]
size=65536
```

> What is the purpose of adding the icache_port and dcache_port?

I'm not very familiar with the port system.

I think ports are used as a way for components to communicate, often in master / slave pairs, e.g. CPU is a master and the cache is a slave. So here I think that the CPU port is there but there is nothing attached to it, so no caches.

For example on the above se.py example we see this clearly:

[image]

Comment: Sanilli Yeah I also think that there are no Icaches and Dcaches in the simple cpu model. I am just confused as to how then gem5 does the simulation of instruction fetch and data fetch. Are they fetched directly from the DRAM in such case?

Comment: @TapojyotiMandal yes, that is what I would expect, although I haven't touched this code myself. From the `config.ini` file, I see without caches `[system.cpu] dcache_port=system.membus.slave[2]` and with `--caches` we have `[system.cpu] dcache_port=system.cpu.dcache.cpu_side` and `[system.cpu.dcache] mem_side=system.membus.slave[2]`, so that seems very likely.

Comment: @ Ciro Santilli That makes sense. The icache_port and dcache_port serve as the interface through which the cpu model gets its instruction and data. If there is no cache then the cpu gets the data from Dram through icache_port/dcache_port. But if there are caches declared then cpu gets data through the same ports but this time the ports are connected to cache simobjects.